# Orthogonal functions and limits of the integral.

Tags: integration, orthogonality

My question is very simple and short.

> Orthogonality Condition: If two functions $f,g$ are orthogonal then
>   $$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=0$$

Question: How we decide $a$ and $b$ what should they be? Or in the definition of orthogonality do we even need interval for integral?(can just indefinite form of the integral satisfy orthogonality?)

If not, then, can we define $a,b$ so that $f,g$ are sometimes orthogonal and sometimes not?

Comment: You captured it correctly in your last sentence. Different choices of $a, b$ lead to different inner products on the function space. Functions orthogonal in one inner product do not have to be in another.

Comment: for example, for fourier series we select these interval so that given function is whole in the interval, kind of?

Comment: I would rather say that differents choices of $a,b$ lead to different functions spaces. Indeed, recall that an inner product defines a norm, and that every norm  $\|\cdot\|$ must satisfies $\|x\|=0 \implies x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orthogonality is tied to the inner product you have on your vector space. Indeed, two vectors are said orthogonal if their inner product is $0$.

That being said, what you have here is an inner product. So the choice of $a,b$ depends on the function space you are considering. For example if you want to study an innner product on continuous functions on $[0,1]$, then you **must** have $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Indeed, considering $a<0$ or $b>1$ makes no sense, because functions are not defined there. If you chose $0<a<b<1$, then it is easy to find a continuous functions satisfying $\int_a^b f(x)^2dx=0$ while $f$ is different from the null function on $[0,1]$. Hence $\int_a^b fg$ fails to be an inner product on the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.